# transparency in CSS sprites

Tags: css

So I am doing my first site with CSS sprites and I was wondering when saving an images as a .png does the amount of whitespace in-between images have an impact on the performance of the image?

For Instance if I where to crame 10 images into a very small canvas would it be smaller then if I where to crame the same 10 images into a nicely spaced out image?

Comment: Ive learned that Safari mobile doesnt always hit the mark spot-on with css background images. 

I tend to leave 4px space between every separate image/element. And what may occur with Safari mobile browser is that you might see glimpse of the adjacted image in element where it doesnt belong. usually in 1px width or height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG does a pretty good job of compressing white space between images so the download size impact of spacing them out is probably very small. The larger image could have a performance impact when decompressed on the browser end, but this will likely only be noticeable on very small systems.

But overall, there is no disadvantage to packing the images in tightly so I would definately suggest doing so.

Comment: Well packing them tightly makes it a little harder on my end to go in and get the coordinates.

Comment: I can't imagine it's a lot harder. If they are rectangular, irregular sizes, and fairly similar in appearance I imagine this could be slight problem, but a single pixel worth of spacing would probably suffice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The more pixels in the image, the more memory taken up when it is converted into an uncompressed bitmap in memory.

This can have a performance impact, especially on low memory systems (it has been quite noticeable on some of the embedded browsers on TVs and set top boxes that I've been working with recently).

Comment: It's weird because I am getting the complete opposite. I have saved the same image in photoshop. One with everything spaced out and another one with all the same images really pressed together and trimmed. However, the spaced out Image is about 6kb smaller...

Comment: The has to do with the compression algorithm being used (and I'd suspect different options for the colour palette before attributing the increase to the image being physically smaller). I was discussing the performance issues for the uncompressed image in the browser memory.